# Continuation (extension) of harmonic functions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, differential-equations, elliptic-pde

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a simply connected smooth Riemannian manifold with smooth boundary and suppose that $U \subset \partial M$ is a smooth open connected subset of the boundary. Now my question is the following:

suppose $f,h \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$. Does there exist a harmonic function in $M$ such that it's Dirichlet and Neumann values on $U$ are $f$ and $h$ respectively?
More precisely does there exist $u$ such that:

$\triangle_g u=0 $ in $M$.

$u|_{U}=f$.

$ \partial_{\nu} u|_U = h$.

Here $\nu$ represents the normal outward unit vector field on $\partial M$.

Note: the answer might be no in general but maybe there is some relaxation on assumptions that makes this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at [Dirichlet-to-Neumann operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Steklov_operator)? There should be a relation at least in the trivial case where $U=\partial M$ is compact.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is no. Let $M$ be a region in the upper half-space $x_1>0$ in $R^n$, (you can take $n=2$) and $\partial M$ contains an open piece $U$ of the plane $x_1=0$.
Take $f=0$ in $U$. Then your harmonic function $u$ extends by symmetry, the extended function will be real analytic on $U$, so $h$ must be real-analytic,
so you cannot assign arbitrary $C^\infty$ function $h$. And of course you cannot assign any $h\in C^\infty_c$, except zero.

Even if your $f$ and $h$ are real-analytic, the answer is still no. Indeed, if $f$ and $h$ are real analytic, consider them as the data for the Cauchy problem
for the Laplace equation. According to Cauchy-Kowalewski theorem, we have uniqueness. But then the analytic continuation of solution to $M$ is not guaranteed. There are no reasonable 
conditions on $f$ and $h$ which will guarantee such an extension.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately for me you are right! Thanks